# SQL A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1364

Tags: mysql, database

I have a website , I try to validate offline payment, but once I'm doing I get this error message

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1364

Field 'puid' doesn't have a default value

```
INSERT INTO `payment` (`user_id`, `package`, `package_id`, `billing_type`, `amount`, `status`, `created_at`, `expire_on`) 
VALUES ('9', 'basic', '1', 'yearly', '45', 'verified', '2021-07-31 21:30:18', '2022-07-31')
```

Filename: models/Admin_model.php

Line Number: 6

Im really noob about this, so please anybody can help me? what should I modify?

Comment: It is telling exactly what the problem is. The table has a column which you have not provided a value for.

Comment: Either assign puid a default value, or include it within the INSERT

Answer (score 1):

Your `paymemt` table is going to have a column called `puid` that is defined as not null.   This column is not in your insert statement so it is complaining that it does not know what value to put in that column. (and columns not in the insert statement are considered to be null).

You can describe the table https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-information.html
and you will see a column called `puid` which will have a datatype but have NO in the NULL column and NULL in the default column.

You either need to insert an appropriate value into the `puid` column or make it auto increment (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

Which you need is very much dependant on the domain.   I am presuming you have got the table definition from somewhere so you will need to consult the documentation to see what value is expected.

Comment: Hello, 

Im the the payment table, but can't see what you are saying, PUID it's not defined as null

Comment: Could you please exlapin me what should I do? as I said, I dont have any idea about this

Comment: See update.   You need to insert a value into `PUID` (either manually or as a default) but I cannot tell you what value you need to use.  You need to check the documentation of the whatever it is you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this :

```
INSERT INTO `payment` (`puid`,`user_id`, `package`, `package_id`, `billing_type`, `amount`, `status`, `created_at`, `expire_on`) 
VALUES ('10000','9', 'basic', '1', 'yearly', '45', 'verified', '2021-07-31 21:30:18', '2022-07-31')
```

Just add `puid` into your insert  , and later set value to it.

Comment: These are my tables in the payment, where I can see PUID with different numbers

Answer (score 0):

Editar Editar
Copiar Copiar
Borrar Borrar
1
02678
2
basic
1
monthly
NULL
NULL
0.00
pending
2021-07-03 04:07:56
2021-08-03

Editar Editar
Copiar Copiar
Borrar Borrar
2
89215
3
basic
1
monthly
NULL
NULL
0.00
pending
2021-07-10 10:53:17
2021-08-10

Editar Editar
Copiar Copiar
Borrar Borrar
3
59846
4
plus
3
monthly
NULL
NULL
15.00
pending
2021-07-15 17:31:13
2021-08-15

Editar Editar
Copiar Copiar
Borrar Borrar
4
85314
5
basic
1
monthly
NULL
NULL
0.00
pending
2021-07-15 17:32:22
2021-08-15

Editar Editar
Copiar Copiar
Borrar Borrar
5
75609
5
basic
1
monthly
NULL
NULL
5.00
pending
2021-07-15 17:38:08
2021-08-15

Editar Editar
Copiar Copiar
Borrar Borrar
6
17532
6
basic
1
monthly
NULL
NULL
0.00
expire
2021-07-15 17:39:43
2021-08-15

Editar Editar
Copiar Copiar
Borrar Borrar
7
65498
6
standared
2
yearly
NULL
NULL
45.00
expire
2021-07-31 06:32:19
2022-07-15

Editar Editar
Copiar Copiar
Borrar Borrar
8
91306
7
basic
1
monthly
NULL
NULL
0.00
expire
2021-07-26 23:17:07
2021-08-26

Editar Editar
Copiar Copiar
Borrar Borrar
9
90846
8
basic
1
monthly
NULL
NULL
0.00
pending
2021-07-26 23:19:16
2021-08-26

Editar Editar
Copiar Copiar
Borrar Borrar
10
75489
9
1
1
monthly
NULL
NULL
5.00
verified
2021-07-31 21:40:53
2021-08-31

Editar Editar
Copiar Copiar
Borrar Borrar
11
18392
10
basic
1
monthly
NULL
NULL
0.00
pending
2021-07-31 19:52:52
2021-08-31

Editar Editar
Copiar Copiar
Borrar Borrar
12
62597
10
plus
3
yearly
NULL
NULL
165.00
pending
2021-07-31 19:53:09
2022-07-31